# How to inherit a function from the main code and execute it inside the module. (this also applies to variables)

Tags: python-3.x, linux

EDIT: I found the solution, if you know an other way, please share.

I've got a question about how to import a function and let it still behave like it is inside the main function.

First example:

```sh
echo -e "a = 1\ndef test():\n    print(a)" > test_function.py
cat test_function.py
## output:
# a = 1
# def test():
#     print(a)
python3 -c "exec('from test_function import *'); a = -1; test()"
## output: 
# 1
```

I would expect as output -1, but it is 1.

Second example:

```sh
echo "test(a)" > test_function.py
cat test_function.py
## output:
# test(a)
python3 -c "exec('a = 1\ndef test(a):\n    print(a)');a = -1;from test_function import *"
## output:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "/tmp/test_function.py", line 1, in <module>
#     test(a)
# NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

How would I be able to inherit the main
variables and functions inside the imported .py file so i could use them like they would be in one main file?

I know you could do it like this but that doesn't help me:

```sh
echo -e "a = 1\ndef test(a):\n    print(a)" > test_function.py
cat test_function.py
## output:
# a = 1
# def test(a):
#    print(a)

python3 -c "exec('from test_function import *'); a = -1; test(a)"
## output:
# -1
```

I've tried searching for this problem but I do not know how to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a second I post my question I thought about the exec function. So this is my solution:

```py
# contents of file_with_additional_functionality.py:
function_you_want_to_call_in_the_file()
```

```py
#/usr/bin/python3
# contents of main.py
def function_you_want_to_call_in_the_file:
    print('Hello from inside the main function.')
with open('file_with_additional_functionality.py') as f:
    exec(f.read())
## output:
# Hello from inside the main function.
```

I hope it's not against the rules of stackoverflow if it is, I will remove the post.